# Button Click action does not register itself the method it is assigned to

Tags: c#, uwp

I've got myself into a little bit of a jam. As I tried to code the entire alphabet into my app, I didn't really feel like typing the letters in one by one, so I used ASCII characters and used a for-loop and inserted them as buttons. So, now I need those buttons to click according to my needs, but somehow I cant seem to figure out what is the problem with the issue. The code is as follows:

```
private void Hangman_OnLoaded()
{
    const int btnSize = 35;
    var c = 0;

    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
    {
        var btn = new Button {
            Content = (char) i,
            Click += GuessClick()
         };
         btn.Width = btn.Height = btnSize;
         var margin = btn.Margin;
         margin.Left = c += 37;
         btn.Margin = margin;
         GridMain.Children.Add(btn);
    }
}

private void GuessClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var choice = sender as Button;
    if (choice == null || !copyCurrent.Contains(choice.DataContext.ToString())) return;
    var temp = copyCurrent.ToCharArray();
    var find = copyCurrent.ToCharArray();
    var guessChar = choice.DataContext.ToString().ElementAt(0);

    for (var index = 0; index < find.Length; index++) {
        if (find[index] == guessChar) {
            temp[index] = guessChar;
        }
    }
    copyCurrent = new string(temp);
    DisplayTheWord();
}
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly is not working.  Is it that your `GuessClick` method isn't being called?  Is there some side effect you are expecting that you are not seeing?  Have you attached with a debugger and verified anything?  Please clarify what is not working.

Comment: _So, now I need those buttons to click according to my needs, but somehow I cant seem to figure out what is the problem with the issue._ ...you need to tell us what you're attempting to accomplish with that code, **and** what it is or is not currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a stab at "Psychic Debugging" this code.  There are lots of things that can be improved, changed, etc, but I am guessing this is where you may be having an issue:

```
var temp = copyCurrent.ToCharArray();
var find = copyCurrent.ToCharArray();
var guessChar = choice.DataContext.ToString().ElementAt(0);
for (var index = 0; index < find.Length; index++) {
    if (find[index] == guessChar) {
        temp[index] = guessChar;
    }
}
copyCurrent = new string(temp);
```

No matter what the `guessChar` is, at the end of this block of code `copyCurrent` will be unchanged (as far as what the actual string content of `copyCurrent` is).  First you make two arrays that are identical.  Then you are looping through the `find` array looking for the `guessChar`.  If you find the `guessChar` then you are "modifying" the `temp` array to have `guessChar` at the very same index where you found it in `find`.  Since both arrays are identical, the end result is that no "change" takes place.  Once you have executed the loop you are creating a new string from the `temp` array, but since both `find` and `temp` are identical and unchanged after this loop, you effectively are making a new string that is identical to the one you started with.  I don't know what you are expecting this code to do, but I am assuming this is not it.

I am going to assume (from the load method name) that this is a game of hangman and that at the outset of the game `copyCurrent` has some content like "????" and that you have some other variable, maybe called `answer` and it would have the content, for example, "food".  If that is the case, then you would just need to modify these two lines:

```
var temp = copyCurrent.ToCharArray();
var find = answer.ToCharArray();
```